# Set div class with jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

tell me how can I put in the cookies to the value in going the pages of the result remained the same

```
  $('.doodle_swit').click(function() {
                    $('.main_wrapper').toggleClass('no_doodle');
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So read the cookie and set the cookie

```
$('.doodle_swit').click(function() {
    var status = $('.main_wrapper').toggleClass('no_doodle').hasClass("no_doodle");
   $.cookie('no_doodle', status ? "true" : "false");  //set the state into the cookie
});
$('.main_wrapper').toggleClass('no_doodle', $.cookie('no_doodle')==="true");  //read it on page load and set the class
```